# Restoring stock Rom to HTC desire S

Tags: htc-desire-s, stock-rom

OK, I know there's stuff out there on this - but tbh I can't understand it.

I have a UK HTC Desire S on T-mobile. I used the official HTC download to upgrade to ICS last year (it was not OTA but on their website). However, when I came to unlock the phone recently (to allow my daughter to use it on another network) I cannot get it to prompt me for the unlock code.

I've performed a "factory reset" but that didn't help, and the best advice I can find online seems to indicate I should  restore the original OS. But I've not the faintest idea how to do this.

I'm not sure what other info to give - it is currently running 4.0.4 and Sense 3.6.

IF there's a dummies guide to this somewhere, I'm happy to be pointed - but I can't find it.

Comment: Isn't your question rather "how to sim-unlock the device"? If so, rather check the [questions tagged sim-unlocking](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sim-unlocking), and (if still needed) ask for that. And try avoiding the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/192154) ;)

Comment: Thanks. I looked there. However, I seemed to understand the problem was that I needed to restore the original T-mobile related OS, and I don't have a clue how to do that. So that's what I'm asking about. First post here, so sorry if I've got the format wrong.

Comment: Our premise is: Don't ask how to achieve the "possible solution" you have in mind, but rather ask for a solution to your direct problem. There might be something else even working much better, and saving you a lot of headache.

Comment: Frankly, I only asked a question best way I could. Obviously didn't read up on house rules enough to do it properly. OK, I'll go ask somewhere else. But this is not a good way to encourage participation in your club

Comment: No offense meant, Alistair. I just tried to help the best way I can. If you are not interested in alternatives (which might prove the better approach or not), you do not need to heed my recommendation. Just leave the question as-is, and I even wish you the best answers to it. You might even end up with the original ROM successfully installed (keeping my fingers crossed for that), but still not be able to unlock – which is what I am afraid of.